# Помогите написать вложенный цикл через Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать такой метод с вложенным циклом через Stream API:

```
public List<Employee> getEmployeesByJobVacancyName(List<Employee> employeeList, String jobVacancyName){
       List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Employee employee : employeeList) {
            for (JobVacancy vacancy : employee.getVacancies()) {
                if (vacancy.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(jobVacancyName)) {
                   list.add(employee);
                }
            }
        }
        return  list;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return employeeList.stream()
                   .filter(e -> e.getVacancies()
                                 .stream()
                                 .anyMatch(jobVacancyName::equalsIgnoreCase))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: ваш код отличается поведением от того кода, который представлен в вопросе - у вас дубликатов не будет в выводе, а в коде из вопроса они возможны ( если у одного employee будет несколько вакансий, удовлетворяющих условию, то в листе будут дубликаты этих employee, а у вас - нет

Comment: Если нужны дубликаты, то ещё проще. Вопрос в том, нужны ли.

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: @limbus если ответ помог вам, [отметьте его решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).